# Showing $(p \to q) \to r\not\equiv p \to (q \to r).$

Tags: logic

By creating a truth table for both of these propositions I know that they are not equivalent.

Using laws of propositional logic, how can i go to show that these two are not equivalent:

$$(p \to q) \to r$$   and  $$p \to (q \to r).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'implication equivalence', $\phi\to\psi\equiv \neg \phi\vee\psi$, and 'implication negation', $\neg(\phi\to\psi)\equiv \phi\wedge\neg \psi$ we see: $$(p\to q)\to r\equiv (p\wedge\neg q)\vee r\\p\to(q\to r)\equiv \neg p\vee\neg q\vee r$$

Both will be true when $r$ is, yet *when $r$ is false*, and *$p$ is false*, then the second will be true, yet the first will be false.   Therefore they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

[Consider when both $p$ and $r$ are false but $q$ is true.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((p%E2%86%92q)%E2%86%92r)%E2%86%94(p%E2%86%92(q%E2%86%92r)))

Comment: This was found via the [method of analytic tableaux](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Answer (score 1):

You show that they're not equivalent by giving truth values for $p$, $q$, and $r$ such that the two statements have different truth values.

Comment: I did the truth tables for both already.. I know that they are not equivalent. All i want to know is how to use the laws of proposition to prove that it isn't.

Comment: The formulas of propositional logic don't prove that things aren't equivalent.  It would be like trying to use the associative and commutative laws to prove that $2\neq 3$.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this... Elaborating off your answer how would i go about finding those truth values??